# vb6 error code 800A0401 on open for as statment to write to file

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I am trying to run the following vbs script but keep getting error 800A0401(error: Expected end of statment), line 1 column 19.

```
Open "C:\log.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, "testing"
Close #1
```

Comment: VBScript is not VB6. Which is it you're using? They're not synonymous. Also, did you even Google the error code? A quick search of `error code 800a0401 vbscript` turns up many answers, including [this one](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A0401.htm). A quick search of `vbscript open file for appending` turned up some useful information, also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I looked up syntax on google and it looks correct, retyped it, it's a .vbs file, thanks will take a look at link you sent and if needed continue to google, sure I will find solution eventually

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in VBScript, you have to use the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat):

```
Const ForAppending = 8

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\log.txt", ForAppending)
f.WriteLine "testing"
f.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

The code I was trying to run turned out to be VB6 code, I was under the impression it was VBScript. The background is I had a lengthy function which someone emailed me to troubleshoot. I was under the impression it was a VBScript so I copied and pasted it into VBScript file and ran it. It was getting a compile time error at 'Open "C:\log.txt" For Append As #1'

I did not have a VB6 environment installed, but was able to run this using excel VBA. At this point I believe Open command does not exist in VBScript but does exist in VB6 and VBA.

Thank you to all who might have looked at this and tried to help me.

Comment: +1. Exactly. Open statement exists in VB6 and VBA but not VBScript. VB6 is 99% identical to VB6.